# Issue in JQuery Confirmation Dialog inside form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

In a JQuery dialog I have four fields. When I click on Save button I needs to check and validate the following

1. Validate all required fields ( On submit of form using validate.js and unobstrusive.js )
2. Check the value of dropdown and if it is of a partcular type ie (Redundant), Show user a confirmation dialog.
3. If the user confirm by pressing Yes, then close the confirmation dialog and call Ajax

But the problem is when I confirm by clicking Yes button on confirmation dialog, the dialog closes but the execution is not going down.

ie, Serializing the form data and make an Ajax call to call the webservice.

Please can anyone help.

```
$(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $('#result').html(" ");

            var redunt = null;
            redunt = $(ClientCrud_StatusCodeId).find('option:selected').text();

            if ($(ClientCrud_StatusCodeId).find('option:selected').text() == "Redundant") {
                $('#clientRedundantMessage2').html("Client once made redundant cannot be reactivated. Are you sure ?");
                $("#RedundantMessage2").dialog(
                    {
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 170,
                        width: 420,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: "Confirmation for Redundant",
                        Content: "Fields cannot be left blank.",
                        buttons: {
                            "Yes": function () {
                                redunt = "Active";
                                $('#RedundantMessage2').dialog('close');
                            },
                            "No": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }) //.dialog("widget").draggable("option", "containment", "none");
                $("#RedundantMessage2").dialog("open");
            }

            if ($(this).valid()) 
            {
                debugger;
                if (redunt == "Active") {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        error: function (request) {
                            $("#result").html(request.responseText);
                            //    event.preventDefault();
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result == "success") {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/Client/ClientGrid",
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: { "page": 0 },
                                    datatype: 'json',
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $('#grid').html(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        alert('Server error');
                                    }
                                });

                                $('#myEditClientDialogContainer').dialog('close');
                                $('#myEditClientDialogContainer').remove()
                            }
                            else {
                                clearValidationSummary();
                                var a = '<ul><li>' + result + '</li></ul>';
                                $('#result').html(a);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            $("#griderrormsg1 li").hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
            return false;
        });

        editallowed = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a issue with the sequence of code, when the function `$("#RedundantMessage2").dialog( ...... );` execute don't wait for the user response in this case "yes" or "no" so... your flag `redunt = "Active"` don't make sense.

the buttons option has function that execute when the opcion is choosen, so you must call a function to execute the post

```
$(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $('#result').html(" ");

            var redunt = null;
            redunt = $(ClientCrud_StatusCodeId).find('option:selected').text();

            if ($(ClientCrud_StatusCodeId).find('option:selected').text() == "Redundant") {
                $('#clientRedundantMessage2').html("Client once made redundant cannot be reactivated. Are you sure ?");
                $("#RedundantMessage2").dialog(
                    {
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 170,
                        width: 420,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: "Confirmation for Redundant",
                        Content: "Fields cannot be left blank.",
                        buttons: {
                            "Yes": function () {
                                redunt = "Active";
                                trySend();
                                $('#RedundantMessage2').dialog('close');
                            },
                            "No": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }) //.dialog("widget").draggable("option", "containment", "none");
                $("#RedundantMessage2").dialog("open");
            }



            $("#griderrormsg1 li").hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
            return false;
        });

        editallowed = true;
    });
```

the other js function

```
function trySend(){

    if ($('#IdOfYourForm').valid()) 
        {
            debugger;
            if (redunt == "Active") {

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    error: function (request) {
                        $("#result").html(request.responseText);
                        //    event.preventDefault();
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == "success") {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Client/ClientGrid",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: { "page": 0 },
                                datatype: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#grid').html(data);
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert('Server error');
                                }
                            });

                            $('#myEditClientDialogContainer').dialog('close');
                            $('#myEditClientDialogContainer').remove()
                        }
                        else {
                            clearValidationSummary();
                            var a = '<ul><li>' + result + '</li></ul>';
                            $('#result').html(a);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Zach. I tried in that way but no luck. It's coming to the trysend method but Isvalid was not working. So I put the code inside  trysend in the same place of function call. Than validation is working but after that it is not hitting the controller class, but I am getting a success response and rendering the whole page with grid in the dialog itself.

Comment: oh! so sorry man, I write `$(this).valid()` but in that point `this` is not the form so you must refer with a selector like `$('#IdOfYourForm').valid()` check it out now...

Comment: Thanks Zach. Apologize for delay in getting back. It's working fine now.